# Using external js file in vue file with Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vue.js

I am working on a project which is used typescript, vue and webpack together. I have created some components and i can use them by importing. However i have different js files in another root folder like site.js, ruler.js, color.js, speech.js, drware.js and etc. Schema is like below

```
+|dist
 ----build.js
+|src
 ----index.ts
  +|main
    ----Header.vue
    ----Footer.vue
    ----Body.vue
+|lib
 ----site.js
 ----ruler.js
 ----drawer.js
 ----color.js
```

webpack config is getting index.ts from src folder which is shown above. When I don't use some functions (like jquery plugins or some special funciton) everything is fine. But when i use a functon from site.js webpack fives error like cannot resolve "ruler" from site.js

I have tried to concat by giving second entry in webpack.config.js but it didn' solve my problem. I wonder how to to resolve external js files in vue or ts files using webpack. I alson tried

```
require(""../src/site.js)
```

but it didn't work too.

Edit : If i concat the js files manually and give it as script source on html it works without problem but i cannot merge all files like or i don't want to use "gulp" to concat them

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including a script-loader into your webpack's configuration?

Webpack is a bundler, not a script loader itself. I would recommend you to follow [webpack's official instructions](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/) to add a script loader.

Good luck!